# viewChild declaration expected

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Hi I am new to angular while I am trying to learn rxjs , on following the tutorial i got this error, I tried many ways but not working anything.

previous error was 'error TS7008: Member '(Missing)' implicitly has an 'any' type.' and I changed the "tsconfig.json" strict =false. now I am getting this error on the picture I attached please help me to resolve

code part------

```
export class RxjsComponent implements OnInit {
  // agents: any = [];
  
  @ViewChild(validate);
  validate!:ElementRef;
```

error----------
Error: src/app/rxjs/rxjs.component.ts:12:23 - error TS1146: Declaration expected.
[image]

Comment: I think, ViewChild is used for Accessing Child component which is part of Angular and Rxsj is a separate Library. Can you please explain more what are you trying to achieve from ViewChild. For description Please see example here, https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description

Comment: iam just following this tutorial for learning purpose.while coding with the tutor i faced the issue.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QuyRQtICrHs&list=PLp50dWW_m40WID0zCrftuRCVa3mCaxYG6&index=9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'validate' is the name which is passed in Component.html file within any tag which starts with #. like in

```
<p #validate></p>
```

You can try this :

```
@ViewChild('validate') !: ElementRef;
```

Comment: @ViewChild('validate') validate: any;   some changes in your syntax saved my day. viewchild syntax has changed i think

Answer (score 0):

@ViewChild('validate') validate: any

finally this works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).